# Datastax Enterprise Sqoop demo, got exceptions

Tags: sqoop, datastax-enterprise

I try to run the sqoop demo from Datastax Enterprise 4.8, I set up an Analytics cluster of 4 nodes, then with another node set up MySql, and populate the data as in the demo example, I followed all the steps of the demo, and everything seems working fine until the point where I actually run the sqoop data migration command. All DBs are created correctly, and cluster is running fine (I can see it with nodetool status and with OpsCenter), but when I run the sqoop command, I got an exception:

```
host# /bin/dse sqoop --options-file /usr/share/dse/demos/sqoop/import.options
/usr/share/dse/bin/dse.in.sh: line 4: /bin/dse-client-tool: No such file or directory
Unable to start sqoop: jobtracker not found
```

The import.options file:

```
*cql-import
--table
npa_nxx
--cassandra-keyspace
npa_nxx
--cassandra-table
npa_nxx_data
--cassandra-column-mapping
npa:npa,nxx:nxx,latitude:lat,longitude:lon,state:state,city:city
--connect
jdbc:mysql://10.xxx.xxx.xxx/npa_nxx_demo
--username
root
--password
xxxxx
--cassandra-host
10.xxx.xxx.xxx,10.xxx.xxx.xxx*
```

anyone has ideas why is this error? I reinstalled the DSE, and still got the same... Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the command is "/bin/dse sqoop --options-file /usr/share/dse/demos/sqoop/import.options", the error message is next. The command and output somehow go to the same line in the above post.

Comment: How did you install DSE? as in was it a package install (apt-get, yum) or tar ball? Also, can you try running /usr/bin/dse sqoop rather than /bin/dse sqoop and see if that works?

Comment: I used the installer in text mode. Yes I tried /bin/dse sqoop -help, it gives the same error: /usr/share/dse/bin/dse.in.sh: line 4: /bin/dse-client-tool: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, need to do a softlink of the dse-client-tool in /bin dir:

`# ln -s /usr/shares/dse/bin/dse-client-tool /bin/dse-client-tool`

then it works, not sure why the link not created during the installation...

Answer (score 0):

Start DSE as an analytics node.

Edit /etc/default/dse, set HADOOP_ENABLED=1 in the cassandra.yaml to start the DSE service.

bin/dse cassandra -t